# Forecasting and numerical stability - how to handle added constants post forecast?

Tags: forecasting

The Python `statsforecast` package has some recommendations when simulating / generating time series, that we can add a constant to avoid computational problems: https://github.com/Nixtla/statsforecast/blob/main/experiments/ray_ets/experiment.py

Basically, they just do this:

```
# the target variable for univariate forecast
df['y'] += 10
```

They note the following:

```
# add constant to avoid numerical errors
# in production settings we simply remove this constant
# from the forecasts
```

My question is on this last part. Consider a few scenarios containing a forecast and a prediction interval, assuming the forecast was made with the +10 constant.

```
Forecast 1: 
** Forecast ** | ** Low 90 ** | ** High 90 ** |
    8                 14             22

Forecast 2:
** Forecast ** | ** Low 90 ** | ** High 90 ** |
    0                 0              21
```

To correct the effect of the constant, do we subtract -10 from all values, to include the prediction intervals?